# Does the Warzone queue launch with uneven teams?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I am growing pretty tired of getting into a match with uneven teams and having little to no hope of winning. Does the Warzone queue launch with uneven teams? I am just getting unlucky and getting paired with people that don't actually "Join" the Warzone?

Comment: What do you mean by "pop"?

Comment: @svick I'd assume he's referring to the programming term which essentially means to take an item from a list (removing it from the list), and do something with it.

Answer (score 1):

I have nothing to back this up, but it wouldn't make sense for the queue to "pop" with uneven teams. What you're most likely seeing is that people who were queued either declined the warzone or were AFK at the time the queue popped.